# Check content overflow from responsive div

Tags: jquery, html, responsive-design, bootstrap-4

I have a page that I worked with bootstrap to be responsive. That page will contain 3 or 4 divs like the one in this image:

[image]

The red icons of each div will be displayed dynamically, so when there are enough icons it will overflow the div, and so, the scroll from the bottom will be used to move along.

Is there a way so I can check if the content in a div has an overflow in order to show the scrollbar just when is needed? Is there any jquery function to check if a responsive div has an overflow into its content?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/WGCyu/2792/

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your response. But, in my case, icons overflows vertically, and if I set `overflow-x: scroll`, nothing happens, only vertical scroll shows. But I need an horizontal scroll.

So, from another point of view, is it possible to force that when icons overflow the div, they move to another "column" in the same div and not growing vertically but instead horizontally?